# Why does this code result in a NumberFormatException?

Tags: java

I was trying to run the following line of code:

```
 System.out.println("11111111111111111111111111111111 is " + Integer.parseInt("11111111111111111111111111111111", 2));
```

and the result is:

```
java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "11111111111111111111111111111111"
at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:495)
```

I expected it to parse that string into -1, because when I do the following:

```
System.out.println(-1 + " is " + Integer.toBinaryString(-1));
```

I get the output:

```
-1 is 11111111111111111111111111111111
```

What is going on here?

Comment: Negative integers are stored as a complement, not sure which. So you always have 1 less bit to store integers because the last one is the sign (32 bit signed means 31 bits for numbers and 1 for sign). `-1` is a lot of ones because it's all the bits flipped with the sign bit flipped too. You probably put too many bits in the first one.

Comment: integer allows numbers up to 2147483647

Comment: The above 2 comments completely answer the question.  Bravo for a rapid turnaround.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Integer.toBinaryString` treats the `int` value as an *unsigned* integer, as per [the documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#toBinaryString-int-):

> Returns a string representation of the integer argument as an unsigned integer in base 2.
>
> The unsigned integer value is the argument plus 2<sup>32</sup> if the argument is negative; otherwise it is equal to the argument. This value is converted to a string of ASCII digits in binary (base 2) with no extra leading 0s.

... whereas `Integer.parseInt` assumes that if you want a negative number, you'll have a negative sign at the start. In other words, the two operations aren't just the reverse of each other.

Now you could get what you want by parsing it as a `long` (with `Long.parseLong(text, 2)` and then casting the result back to `int`. That works as you *can* represent 2<sup>32</sup>-1 as a `long`, and when you cast it to `int` you'll get -1.

Comment: Ah, interesting. Do you know why Integer.toBinaryString treats the int value as unsigned when ints in java are signed?

Comment: @jcm: Not sure, to be honest.

Answer (score 0):

If you think of your ones `11111111111111111111111111111111` as a sequence of **Bits** it converts to something like

```
1111 1111 - 1111 1111 - 1111 1111  - 1111 1111
```

That's **four bytes** worth of 'int', and is the binary representation of -1

If you parse that large a number on the other hand using Integer.parseInt(), that number (interpreted to the base 10) is way to long to fit into int.

Using `Long.parseLong("", 2)` you could read in that bit-string - and if you casted it back into int, you would indeed gat back your -1

```
int reverse = (int)Long.parseLong("11111111111111111111111111111111", 2)
```